# Does the StartNew hold a thread for the duration of a call?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, threadpool, task-parallel-library

I was under the assumption that StartNew only used a thread from the ThreadPool while work was actually being done and would release it when it was waiting. For example:

```
    Task.Factory.Startnew() {
          () => {
                    ..
                    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                     ..
                    }
                }
}
```

So say above the cmd.ExecuteReader() was a very slow stored procedure that took 10 minutes to run. I thought the TPL would release the thread back to the pool and not hold onto the thread the entire time. Is this incorrect? If not what is the big advantage of the TPL approcach to say a background worker thread. I started thinking my assumptions weren't true after reading [Stephen Toub's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not how threads work in .Net. If you make a blocking call, the thread has to actually block, it can't do anything else. There is no “magic” in TPL that would do that.*

Basically, there is not much difference between calling `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` and `Task.Factory.StartNew()`. But using TPL has many advantages, like:

1. Support for cancellation.
2. Support for continuations (`task.ContinueWith()`).
3. Support for other schedulers other than the thread pool. The most frequently used one is the synchronization context, useful in GUI applications.
4. Inlining tasks (if you start waiting on a task that hasn't been started yet, it can start executing on the current thread).
5. Thread-local queues of tasks, which can improve performance.
6. `Task` is a single abstraction of something that will finish in the future, it doesn't have to be a compute-bound background operation. This will become even more important in .Net 4.5.

* C# 5 has compiler magic that can make your asynchronous code look like synchronous code today. But blocking call will still remain blocking call.

Comment: Thanks i guess i got that confused with calling asp.net async operations and calling some function that is using the IO Completion port which allows you to release the thread back to the pool